# Add dependency management pom from private repo

Tags: java, repository, maven-3

I work on a project that need a big number of library or module. All dependencies are stored in my private maven repository ( using AWS S3 ). I setup everything and the project work well.

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-repo.notelis.com</id>
            <url>s3://maven-repo.notelis.com/snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repo.notelis.com</id>
            <url>s3://maven-repo.notelis.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

That is the distribution management. I used the correct transporter in build section:

```xml
<extensions>
            <extension>

                <groupId>com.github.noyessie.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
```

To centralize the dependencies version management, I decided to use maven BOM. for that, I follow the maven documentation and everything work well locally ( locally i used `mvn install` ). to make it available for the other project.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.neyos.saas</groupId>
                <artifactId>notelis-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${notelis.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

The problems begins when i try to build a project in my CI. I got the error :

```sh
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.neyos.saas:notelis-dependencies:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ line 120, column 16 -> [Help 2]
```

It seems like maven only check the dependencies of section `dependencyManagement` in central repository, not in my private repository. So the is a way to ask to maven to fetch the dependency present in section `dependencyManagement` in my private repository. Not on central repository ?

PS: I don't want to use central repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For maven to search dependencies in some repository you must enlist that repository in repositories section of pom-file.